# i want to open a div after countdown timer stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-countdown

I am building an aptitude test with a timer. i want to show a div of **time out** on countdown finish. and is it possible to show a **Lean Modal Popup ** box on countdown finish.  Please help!!!. Heres the code

Javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function CountDownTimer(duration, granularity) {
  this.duration = duration;
  this.granularity = granularity || 1000;
  this.tickFtns = [];
  this.running = false;
}

CountDownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
  if (this.running) {
    return;
  }
  this.running = true;
  var start = Date.now(),
      that = this,
      diff, obj;

  (function timer() {
    diff = that.duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    if (diff > 0) {
      setTimeout(timer, that.granularity);
    } else {
      diff = 0;
      that.running = false;
    }

    obj = CountDownTimer.parse(diff);
    that.tickFtns.forEach(function(ftn) {
      ftn.call(this, obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
    }, that);
  }());
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.onTick = function(ftn) {
  if (typeof ftn === 'function') {
    this.tickFtns.push(ftn);
  }
  return this;
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.expired = function() {
  return !this.running;
};

CountDownTimer.parse = function(seconds) {
  return {
    'minutes': (seconds / 60) | 0,
    'seconds': (seconds % 60) | 0
  };
};


window.onload = function () {
    var display = document.querySelector('#time'),
        timer = new CountDownTimer(5),
        timeObj = CountDownTimer.parse(5);

    format(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);

    timer.onTick(format);

    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        timer.start();
    });

    function format(minutes, seconds) {
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}

if(display.textContent == 0){


            document.querySelector("#div1").style.display="block";





}



};



</script>
```

Html

```
<button>Start Count Down</button>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>
```

div to show

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none;" ><p>Hello</p></div>
```

Comment: I think your problem is that you are specifying a display: none in html. As far as I know, javascript will not overwrite that, because the inline-style takes preference. Try hiding the div with CSS, like specifying a <style> tag, or set it to display:none when the page loads the first time instead of giving it an inline-style

Comment: Sorry, the above comment is not true. Your check in javascript  only executes when the page loads, so I moved your code a little bit. I will post your fix soon as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the thing is, you have this piece of javascript code:

```
    window.onload = function () {
    var display = document.querySelector('#time'),
        timer = new CountDownTimer(5),
        timeObj = CountDownTimer.parse(5);

    format(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);

    timer.onTick(format);

    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        timer.start();
    });

    function format(minutes, seconds) {
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}

if(display.textContent == 0){


            document.querySelector("#div1").style.display="block";





}
```

At the bottom, you have an "if" statement.

Just move that if statement into the "format" function as follow:

```
    window.onload = function () {
        var display = document.querySelector('#time'),
            timer = new CountDownTimer(5),
            timeObj = CountDownTimer.parse(5);

        format(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);

        timer.onTick(format);

        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
            timer.start();
        });



 function format(minutes, seconds) {
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;

        console.log(display.textContent);

        if(display.textContent == "00:00") {
            document.querySelector("#div1").style.display="block";
        }
    }
};
```

Your code, the way it currently is, is not performing the check on every tick.

Also, you are not checking against "0". The value should be "00:00"

Of course, you can move the check to show the div into the tick event, but that is totally up to you.

Comment: Thanx a lott @Frederik .It worked perfectly.. Can you please tell me how can i put a lean modal popup instead of that div

Comment: @ChiragSharma - By "Lean modal popup", do you mean that you want the div to cover the whole screen, so that the users cannot click on something else? If you want that, you can just make the div "fixed" (position: fixed), and set it's vertical height and width (height: 100vh and width: 100vw) to cover the screen, and make it's z-index: 1000, for example. You may also need to set the div's top: 0px and left: 0px if the div is a bit off